# Does Rust have "use foo::*" with renaming?

Tags: import, rust

Is it possible to `use foo::* with {T=T_renamed}`, or something equivalent, like

```
use foo::* hiding {T};
pub type T = foo::T<i32>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. For that matter, glob imports are generally discouraged.

Comment: Sad! The ability to do things like this easily makes OCaml's module system really powerful.. My use case looks something like http://pastebin.com/D5A28sJK - any ideas?

Comment: @bfops: I’d just say don’t use glob imports.

Comment: Are glob imports still discouraged for `pub use` re-exports in libraries, or just for general use?

Comment: This definitely falls under the "re-export" case in my head.. I don't want to change my re-export list every time the module changes, but I do want to override the definition of T..

Comment: My own personal opinion on glob imports is that `use super::*;` in a tests module is the only place they should be used—and even there they aren’t *necessary*.